# jmol java applet : java.io.FilePermission error.

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, applet

I am trying to embed a Jmol java applet on a test website. Currently everything is local (ie on my hard drive).

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../Jmol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jmolInitialize("../");
      jmolApplet(2000, "load POSCAR.xyz");
    </script>
```

when I open the .html web page, I get an error

"Exception: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/marco/Desktop/fridb/static/jmol/test/POSCAR.xyz " "read")

how do I change the code to allow my POSCAR.xyz to be read?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  It also seems to have been reported here, http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14358. I anticipate starting a new thread with details of my problem soon.  I'll link to this post when I do.